# Airflow Error : strptime() argument must be str, not Proxy

Tags: airflow

In Airflow, we are using airflow macro 'next_ds' for some date calculation :

```
{{ macro.ds_add(next_ds,-1) }}
```

However, after airflow upgrade to 2.2.2, next_ds was change from date to Proxy.

We tried below in custom function but got error :

```
datetime.strptime(ds,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Error :
TypeError : strptime() argument must be str, not Proxy.

According to https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19592 upgrading is the optimal solution.
Is there any other way to calculate next execution date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to mimic behaviour of next_ds:

Import croniter package and define your own schedule which uses same syntax as airflow cron:

```
import croniter
schedule = '0 6 * * sat'   

# Custom function
def next_exec_date(dt,days_delta):
    cron = croniter.croniter(schedule, dt)
    return cron.get_next(datetime) + timedelta(days=days_delta) 

#Also, define below in dag_args :
# 'user_defined_macros': {
#     'custom_next_exec_date': next_exec_date,
# }
```

Now, use below as macro just like next_ds :

( custom_next_exec_date(ds,-1)

Cheers!!